# How to compare ranked lists

Tags: list, compare, ranking

I have two lists of ranked items. Each item has an rank and an associated score. 
The score has decided the rank. The two lists can contains (and usually do) different items, that is their intersection can be empty. I need measures to compare such rankings. 
Are there well-known algorithms  (in literature or real-world systems) to do so ? 
The measure of distance should take into account the scores as well as the ranks of the items.

Comment: [Cavnar & Trenkle](http://www.nonlineardynamics.com/trenkle/papers/sdr94ps.gz) have a nice and simple measure of the difference between two ranked lists. The [Wilcoxon ranked-sum test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) gives a measure of (dis)similarity between scored lists, but if the intersection of both lists is empty, you'll have to invent a hack (e.g. use some maximum score; see again Cavnar & Trenkle).

Comment: The referenced article 'N-Gram-Based Text Categorization' (1994) provides a possible measure of distance between ranked lists. However the given example (comparing ranked lists of n-gram) do not enter in the detail of corner cases or how to define the 'max' distance in case of no-match. Also the items do not get an associated score.

Comment: Actually, the no-match is discussed, IIRC. When making a top-k list, any item that occurs in only one list gets a penalty of k+1.

Answer (score 34):

This question has never been answered before, but I still think it's important to a lot of people out there:

Your two requirements, i.e. **non-conjointness of lists** and **importance of ranks** are not met by common correlation tests. In addition to that most of them (Kendall-Tau for example) do not take the order into account:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import kendalltau
>>> kendalltau([1,2,3,4,5], [2,1,3,4,5])
KendalltauResult(correlation=0.79999999999999982, value=0.050043527347496564)
>>> kendalltau([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,5,4])
KendalltauResult(correlation=0.79999999999999982, value=0.050043527347496564)
```

The 1st  comparison should yield a significantly smaller value than the 2nd one, because the head of the list is more important than the tail **(2nd requirement)**.

In addition to that one can see that both lists need to be the same size and have the same kind of elements **(1st requirement)**

**Possible solution**:

The measure that satisfies all your needs is called [Rank Biased Overlap](http://codalism.com/research/papers/wmz10_tois.pdf). It's a generalization of the so called average based overlap, which is wonderfully illustrated in this [blog](https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/comparing-ranked-list/).
The same guy also put out an [implementation](https://github.com/ragrawal/measures) of RBO.

*Update Jan 2018:*

- Another implementation of [RBO](https://github.com/dlukes/rbo) for python 3.5.2

Comment: Thanks,, this worked well for me. I have fixed list of stocks [50] and wanted to know how  much they were changing day to day with the leading stocks by score getting more weight. Cheers,

Comment: Really nice article!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe not solving the issue completely, but definitely worth taking a look at [Kendall's weighted tau](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715298000066).

It provides a better way of calculating similarity between ranked lists when order matters as i it allows arbitrary weighting based on rank order.

For example, one may be more interested in upweighting similarity in the top 20 items of the list rather than uniformly.

Also has a nice implementation in [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weightedtau.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are many measures to compare top k (ranked) lists. Some very trivial to compute making several simplifying assumptions, others not so trivial but are more rigorous in their evaluation of rank similarity between lists. A recent paper I came across that deals with this problem in a statistically meaningful way, using concepts from information theory and data compression: http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0110